# Beautiful soup when scraping websites with flask gives bad requests errors

Tags: python, html, flask, beautifulsoup

I have created a simple desktop application without flask where I scrape multiple websites and return their title, however, I am trying to turn this desktop app into a web application using flask. Below I have two html pages (one to insert links which the program can decipher and one for the results of the titles). The issue is that the function to get the titles gives me errors, 404 global page and bad requests for a majority of the websites, despite when running the same function on it's own, it gives all the proper titles of the websites. I have tried running the title function (quickMLA) by connecting a different python script. I have also tried running the whole program in a virtual environment and not in one, but all attempts didn't fix the issue. Any knowledge of what is going on would be awesome!
If you want to test the actual web application where you copy and paste the websites in, copy and paste the list of websites below:

```
https://covid19tracker.ca/provincevac.html?p=ON
https://www.aboutamazon.com/news/company-news/amazons-covid-19-blog-updates-on-how-were-responding-to-the-crisis#covid-latest
https://www.bcg.com/en-us/publications/2021/advantages-of-remote-work-flexibility
https://news.prudential.com/increasingly-workers-expect-pandemic-workplace-adaptations-to-stick.htm
https://www.mckinsey.com/featured-insights/future-of-work/whats-next-for-remote-work-an-analysis-of-2000-tasks-800-jobs-and-nine-countries
https://www.gsb.stanford.edu/faculty-research/publications/does-working-home-work-evidence-chinese-experiment
https://www.livecareer.com/resources/careers/planning/is-remote-work-here-to-stay
https://www.bcg.com/en-us/publications/2021/advantages-of-remote-work-flexibility
```

This is the function that when running on it's own works:

```
import requests
import bs4 as bs

lst = [
    "https://covid19tracker.ca/provincevac.html?p=ON",
    "https://www.ontario.ca/page/reopening-ontario#foot-1",
    "https://blog.twitter.com/en_us/topics/company/2020/keeping-our-employees-and-partners-safe-during-coronavirus.html",
    "https://www.aboutamazon.com/news/company-news/amazons-covid-19-blog-updates-on-how-were-responding-to-the-crisis#covid-latest",
    "https://www.bcg.com/en-us/publications/2021/advantages-of-remote-work-flexibility",
    "https://news.prudential.com/increasingly-workers-expect-pandemic-workplace-adaptations-to-stick.htm",
    "https://www.mckinsey.com/featured-insights/future-of-work/whats-next-for-remote-work-an-analysis-of-2000-tasks-800-jobs-and-nine-countries",
    "https://www.gsb.stanford.edu/faculty-research/publications/does-working-home-work-evidence-chinese-experiment",
    "https://www.livecareer.com/resources/careers/planning/is-remote-work-here-to-stay",
    ]


def quickMLA(lst):
    cited_lst = []
    for websites in range(len(lst)):
        url=lst[websites]
        headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.101 Safari/537.36"}
        source = requests.get(url,headers=headers, timeout=10).content
        soup_page = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'html.parser')
        title = soup_page.find("title").get_text().strip()
        print(title)
quickMLA(lst)
```

This is the whole python code for the flask project which when runs gives me the bad request errors:

```
from flask import Flask,redirect, url_for,render_template,request,session
import requests
import bs4 as bs

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "sourcerer"

@app.route("/", methods=["POST","GET"])
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/cited", methods=["POST"])
def cited():
    doc = request.form['the_document']
    lst = identifyUrls(doc)
    info = quickMLA(lst) 
    return render_template("results.html",info=info)

def identifyUrls(doc):
    temp = -1
    website_urls = []
    for chars in range(len(doc)):
        if doc[chars:chars+6] == "https:":
            temp = chars
        if (doc[chars] == " " or doc[chars] == "\n" or chars+1 == len(doc)) and temp != -1: 
            website_urls.append(doc[temp:chars])
            temp = -1
    return website_urls

def quickMLA(lst):
    cited_lst = []
    for websites in range(len(lst)):
        url=lst[websites]
        headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.101 Safari/537.36"}
        source = requests.get(url,headers=headers, timeout=10).content
        soup_page = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'html.parser')
        title = soup_page.find("title").get_text().strip()
        cited_lst.append(title) 
    return cited_lst

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Html home page (without css):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet"/>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="description" content="..." />
    <title>Sourcerer</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section>
      <div class="header">
        <h2>The Sourcerer</h2>
        <p>Wizard of Citations</p>
      </div>
    </section>
      <div class="main">
        <div class="position">
          <form action="{{url_for('cited')}}" method="POST">
            <textarea class="beg" placeholder="Copy and Paste Document" name="the_document"></textarea>
            <div class='main_button'>
              <input class="c" value="Cite It" type="submit" name="citeme">
            </div>   
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Html results page (without css):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet"/>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <meta name="description" content="..." />
    <title>Sourcerer</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section>
      <div class="header">
        <h2>The Sourcerer</h2>
        <p>Wizard of Citations</p>
      </div>
    </section>
      <div class="main">
        <form action="{{url_for('home')}}" method="POST">
          <textarea class="results">
            {% for cites in info%}
            {{cites}}
            {%endfor%}
          </textarea>
          <div class="main">
            <input class="c" value="Cite Another" type="submit" name="another">
          </div>  
        </form>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you have any idea why this is happening, your knowledge would truly be appreciated!

Comment: Please also include the full error you're getting. It likely provides a valuable clue.

Comment: @DaveW.Smith, When I run the function through the web application with the websites to copy and paste I get: COVID-19 Tracker Canada - Provincial Vaccination Tracker, Amazon’s COVID-19 vaccination and testing blog, Global 404 page, Bad Request, Bad Request, Page not found | Stanford Graduate School of Business Error, Global 404 page

Answer (score 0):

Here's a suggestion for debugging. You're observing that several of the URLs are giving you problems, but it might help to capture what that problem is. Try cutting BeautifulSoup out entirely, and do something like

```
for url in websites:
    try:
        cited_lst.append(url)
        headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.101 Safari/537.36"}
        response = requests.get(url,headers=headers, timeout=10)
        cited_lst.append(str(response.status_code))
    except Exception as ex:
        cited_lst.append(repr(ex))
```

This'll show why some urls are given you problems.

Comment: I get codes of 200, 404, 503 and 400 but when I run the function on its own I only get the code 200. Not sure if that helps

Comment: If 'run on its own' means on your own computer, and you're getting the 404s, 503s, and 400 when you run it on some other computer, several things are possible. It's quite possible given the nature of those links that some of those sites have put in protection against being scraped, possibly by failing requests from certain IP addresses.

Comment: Sorry I didn't quite clarify, by 'run on its own' I mean just running that function in its own python file on my computer which is when I get the 200 codes. But when I run that function with the html in flask still on my computer, I get 404s, 503s and 400s. By the way thank you for your time so far!

Comment: Unless I misunderstand, if you run it from the python file, you're supplying a fixed list of URLs. If you run it through the webapp, you're using URLs that you've extracted from a document. The problem is likely then in `identifyUrls`. Give it closer scrutiny. If it's handing back URLs that start off O.K. but then contain trailing junk, you'd likely get the range of error responses you're seeing.